# C++ std::map with key as vector of objects causing error: operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, stdvector, stdmap

I'm trying to create a std::map with a vector of objects as a key.

```
struct Data {
    int data;
    bool isOptional = false;

    Data(int cdata, bool cisOptional = false) {
        data = cdata;
        isOptional = cisOptional;
    }

    const bool operator < (const Data& other) {
        return std::tie(data, isOptional) < std::tie(other.data, other.isOptional);
    }
};

typedef std::map<std::vector<Data>, std::string> DataMap;
```

```
DataMap datamap;

std::vector<Data> testdata{  Data(1) };
std::vector<Data> testdata2{ Data(1) };
datamap[testdata] = "test";

std::cout << "Count: " << datamap.count(testdata2) << std::endl;
```

However after creating an entry in the map with `testdata`, the Compiler gives the errors

> Error  C2672   'operator __surrogate_func': no matching overloaded function found
>
> Error  C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::less::operator ()(_Ty1 &&,_Ty2 &&) noexcept() const'

Edit

FIXED

changed signature of operator overload from this
`const bool operator < (const Data& other)`

to this
`bool operator < (const Data& other) const`

Comment: `operator<` should be marked as `const`.

Comment: That `operator <` you are attempting to write does not follow a `strict-weak-ordering`, thus your program will have undefined behavior.  A `std::map` wants to know if one item should be inserted before the other, and your check is ambiguous on equal items since you return `true` for equal items.

Comment: `return std::tie(data, isOptional) < std::tie(other.data, other.isOptional);` -- That would be a strict-weak-order.